# how to read the input values from inside the input elements of a selected radio-button tag?

Tags: php, forms

I have the following code,

### HTML

```
<form>
    <label>Form 1<input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" onclick="displayForm(this)"></label>    
    <label>Form 2<input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onclick="displayForm(this)"></label>    
</form>

<form style="visibility:hidden" id="form1" name="form1">
    <label>Form 1<input type="text" id="a1" name="a1"/></label>
    <label>Form 2<input type="text" id="a2" name="a2"/></label>
</form>    

<form style="visibility:hidden" id="form2" name="form2">
    <label>Form 2<input type="text" id="b1" name="b1"/> </label>
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
function displayForm(c){
    if(c.value == "1"){
        document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility='visible';
        document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility='hidden';
    }
    else if(c.value =="2"){
        document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility='hidden';
        document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
```

And I have the following php code to read the input values and put it in a text file, this code worked successfully for other elements, but when I am using this code to read the input elements from inside another form of a selected radio-button tag, it giving the error, undefined element a1.

### PHP

```
file_put_contents($file, "\n a1 value:", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['a1'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

do you think it is because of the form inside another form or is there any other reason, or do I need to put any other id inside $_POST ? I have tried `$_POST['form1.a1']`, but it is also giving undefined error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate in HTML that you want the form `POST`ed:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
```

Update `page.php` to the name of the PHP file processing the form.

It would also be a good idea to wrap all input fields in a single `<form>` tag - you can hide form elements individually within that; there's no need to keep them separate.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to update, i tried with name attribute only, but i am getting the same result

Comment: See my edit. Note that names have to be unique - you have two inputs with a name of `a1` in your code.

Comment: again, i forgot to update, i tried with different name, but the same result

Comment: Have you changed the `<form>` element?

Comment: in my layout, i need to use two different forms to hide some of the elements, when the different option of radiobutton is selected, is there any way to wrap these in a single form ?

Comment: Wrap the inputs in `<div>` tags, and target those using their ids. The current way you're doing it misuses `<form>` tags.

Comment: can i give the same action="page.php" to two different forms

Comment: Yes - but change `page.php` to the actual name of your file.